# Error executing MySQL code

Tags: mysql, sequelpro

I am using SEQUEL Pro and MySQL. When I execute each line individually no errors are generated and code works as expected. When I try to execute all lines together I get the error below.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE pricesOutput (price float, namex varchar(255), updatedAt datetime);

insert into pricesOutput
select 9.99, 'Bosch ZXY', '12/05/12';

select *
from pricesOutput;

drop table pricesOutput;

end$$

delimiter;
```

[ERROR in query 1] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'insert into pricesOutput
select 9.99, 'Bosch ZXY', '12/05/12';

```
select *
from pr' at line 3
```

[ERROR in query 2] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'delimiter;' at line 1

Comment: Having never used sequelpro I don't know if this will work. Your insert statement seems wrong. The correct syntax for insert is; `insert into table (col, col, col) values (val, val, val), (val, val, val)`.

Comment: @doveyg: The syntax used by OP is correct see : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html  and the code runs fine in MySQL workbench

Comment: See my answer below. Is there any reason you are writing the code this way - it is normally used when defining a stored procedure

Answer (score 0):

The DELIMITER $$ line changes the delimiter from ; to $$, so each line needs terminating with $$ instead. END is used for defining procedures so is not required & the final DELIMITER; should have a space before the semi-colon.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE pricesOutput (price float, namex varchar(255), updatedAt datetime)$$
insert into pricesOutput select 9.99, 'Bosch ZXY', '12/05/12'$$
select * from pricesOutput$$
drop table pricesOutput$$
delimiter ;
```

Comment: Thanks Paul, I included the delimiter definition because the example code is taken from a stored procedure. Your suggestion works for the example I gave, but not with the stored procedure.

Comment: DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_fetchPrices2()
BEGIN

DECLARE v_id INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE v_finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE pricesOutput (price float, namex varchar(255), updatedAt datetime);
insert into pricesOutput select 9.99, 'Bosch ZXY', '12/05/12';

DECLARE cursor_price CURSOR FOR select id from products;


END//
DELIMITER ;

Comment: Glad to be of help - I did mention that END is used for defining procedures, so removed it as you said you had problems running the code - you are right that it needs to go back in when you are creating a procedure.

Comment: Can you cast an eye over the code above. Works fine until the temporary table line is added. I can't see why this is causing an issue. Executes the temp table line fine by itself. Thanks

Comment: I think the _DECLARE cursor_price ...._ needs to go before the _CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ...._